# How do I store an image in firebase as a base64 encoded string

Tags: java, android, firebase, base64

Firebase has a 10 MB limit for its fields which are text based. I'd like to know how in an Android app I can save/restore a user's avatar image in firebase as a base64 encoded string.

Comment: Your question is still too broad. What exactly is your problem? Are you asking how to encode an image; or how to actually save it? You see; you name all the relevant terms in your questions; and theoretically you would just need to do some searching to find example code for the various steps you need to implement ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here ;)

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.util.Base64

Basically all the base64 decoders will change the binary file to Strings by Hashing the bit Stream. Sounds complicated but the code that does it is very basic because streaming is so common.

Answer (score 0):

Save the image to internal storage and store the path to the image in firebase.

Then to fetch the image get the path and recreate the image in any of the valid ways